# ubuntu chinese problem

Tags: command-line

Ubuntu 18.04 has set the Chinese language, but some components do not display Chinese, such as system settings terminal or English status, please help solve

Only part of it can now display Chinese status

Comment: Did you try logging out and back in or restarting?

Comment: I have restarted the same problem, the key part is now English.

Comment: Maybe some components are missing Chinese translations. Can you update  a screenshot?

Comment: https://imgur.com/gallery/0zDeMOG

Comment: You can see if some of the components are still in English, not Chinese.          https://imgur.com/gallery/0zDeMOG